# MSTSC using python with prepopulated target or direct connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, operating-system

so i would like to open up mstsc with a prepopulated field of the target or even connecting straight to it via python

currently opening it is easy

```
os.startfile('C:\\Windows\\system32\\mstsc.exe')
```

but how could i prepopulate or even remote connect to the target? is it even possible with python?

Answer (score 0):

okay pretty easy doable

```
import subprocess
     subprocess.call('mstsc /v:yourtarget')
```

it instantly opens mstsc with predefined pc target .. you could define more looking into [mstsc parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc)